# urls amigaveis, voltar ao directorio

Tags: php, html, css, url-amigável

Boa tarde, eu tenho uma duvida, eu implementei urls amigaveis para uma pagina do meu website. Desta forma,

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^investimentos/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ anuncio.php?id=$3&acao=$4
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, o problema é que nesta pagina para ir buscar por exemplo o css tenho de fazer ../../../../******.css ou uma imagem ou links, tenho de recuar sempre (penso que são 4 pastas), existe alguma forma de não ter de fazer isto?

Answer (score 0):

Usa o endereço do teu site no endereço do teu css e imagens.

Por exemplo:
Faz assim:

```
<link href="http://www.teusite.com/assets/_css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

No lugar de:

```
<link href="../assets/_css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```